# Is it possible to get logging into CloudTrail/CloudWatch from AWS cognito user pools with the hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-userpools

I've been looking at events from cognito in cloudtrail, and I get several of them, but not all. After finding [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/02/amazon-cognito-user-pools-now-supports-logging-for-all-api-calls-with-aws-cloudtrail/), it states: **Hosted UI and Federation calls are currently not included in CloudTrail logging events.**

*If it's still not supported, are there any good alternatives to say log number of sign ins, sign ups etc via the hosted ui?*

There seem to be lambda triggers I could use, but I was hoping I didn't need to add an extra lambda purely for logging signin/signup events to cloudwatch, and I don't want to roll my own sign up page for now.

Comment: Lambda triggers are the only way I believe.